# How to generate a random sequence of numbers in python?

Tags: python, random, numbers, unique

I need to create a short unique ID which is a random sequence of numbers in python.  So i need to allocate the short sequence to a user and also store it in a text file

Can some one please help me with this and give me an example??

Comment: read about [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html)

Comment: Python has a random module that can be used to generate random numbers or integers in some specified range

Comment: @NendoTaka, IMO OP needs __unique__ ID

Comment: It is impossible to have both a random and unique number unless you are removing that possibility from the random generation. Just add an if statement to check if it has been used and use a large range.

Answer (score 1):

Use uuid:

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4()
```

results in things like:

```
UUID('35ad767c-da61-4731-adbc-cdd96efac2c4')
```

And a link to the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html